# Displaying package version number (n.n.n.n) in the body of a web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Looking for a way to grab the package version number (that is, the value of `solution.version` that is stored in `package-solution.json` and which is displayed in the app catalog) and render it in a hidden field in the web part, so that we can have our test harness inspect it across site pages.

I see that the `ISolution` interface has this property. But, it doesn't look like that interface is available outside of the gulp package-solution task. Is there any way to access this property at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. This version number is only meant for use inside the package. Each component (web part, extension) has its own version number which is independent of the package version number, which you can access through the `this.manifest.version` property.

Answer (score 1):

Actually using SPFX v1.4.1 you can reference the package version number by updating package.json and then use `this.manifest.version` to display the version number.

Set `"version": "*"` in the webparts ..manifest.json file
and update `"version": "0.0.1"` in the package.json file

For this to work you will need to properly deploy your package to SharePoint using `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship`.

Running `gulp serve --nobrowser` will display version 0.0.1

The package.json version number must be in the 0.0.0 format for this to work.